# Fade in information of ad when hovering unqiue div

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have many images each with their own unique id. each image is a link to its ad. I want to add a hover fadeIn effect that will display some info about that ad on top of the image.

I tried to do something but I don't think I am taking the right approach.
I feel like there is a better way to get the div on top rather than doing margin: -105px 0 0;
Also, I can't think of how to tell it "if id=1 is hovered, fadein id=fade1, else fadeout"

http://jsfiddle.net/mKDP4/4/

**Dynamic div (in php)**

```
<img src="test.jpg" class="ad_cover" id="1">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade1"></div>

<img src="test.jpg" class="ad_cover" id="2">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade2"></div>

<img src="test.jpg" class="ad_cover" id="3">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade3"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.ad_cover').mouseover(function() {
    var ad_id = this.id;
    $('#fade'+ad_id).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.ad_cover').mouseout(function() {
    var ad_id = this.id;
    $('#fade'+ad_id).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ad_cover{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.ad_fade{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-105px 0 0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a heads up, if you aren't using HTML5, `id`s cannot start with numbers. If you are using HTML5 then no worries.

Comment: yeah I am using HTML5 but either way this is just for my question. I am using slightly different names. Just wanted it to look clean over here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with margins in your CSS, you can use `background-image` and place the images inside of your `div` elements like so:

HTML

```
<div class="ad">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
<div class="ad">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
<div class="ad">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ad img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:none;
}
.ad {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(...);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then, using `.hover()` and `.children()`, you can hide/show the content of the `div`s like so:

```
$('.ad').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('img').fadeIn('slow');
},
function() {
    $(this).children('img').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This way, you don't have to mess with combining IDs and classes and only have to use the one class on the parent `div`s.

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9zP7g/

Comment: the thing is i have a while loop that retrieves ads with images from the database so i cannot put this in css like that.

Comment: any idea how to do it with the database dynamically?

Comment: What database? How are you currently doing it dynamically? You can use whatever variable you have setup to pull the images and just use that in your CSS but it all depends on your setup. I think that might be best suited for another question.